# RESTful- Which HTTP Status to Return on False

Tags: web-services, rest, http-status-codes

I have a RESTful service where I need to return a boolean equivalent.  If the query returns true, I will return a 200 status, but am not sure what to return on false.  I was thinking it should be a 4** status, but which one?  Would 404 be considered the most appropriate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should return 200 on both cases.  Then return a content-type header of text/plain and include the string "true" or "false".
Most languages should have no problem parsing those strings into a native type.

Comment: That makes much more sense than my original approach. Thanks!